# get image from address book and stored it to NSmutablearray but while showing it gives `EXCBAD Error` in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

hi i am creating custom address book in this i want to get only this users who have email address all things work perfectly but when i try to show image in tableview it gives me `EXCBAD Error`. i have code like this

```
            ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);

        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++) {

            UIImage *img;

            if(ABPersonHasImageData(person))
            {
//              img = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person,kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)];
                img = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person)];
//                if(img != nil)
//                {
//                    [arrImage addObject:img];
//                }
//                else
//                {
                    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-9.png"];
                    [arrImage addObject:img];
//                }
            }else
            {
                img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-9.png"];
                [arrImage addObject:img];
            }


            NSString* email = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j);


//          [arrImage addObject:img];
            [arrEmail addObject:email];

            [img release];
            [email release];
        }
        CFRelease(emails);
    }
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    CFRelease(people);
```

here in above code i am fetching image and store image in NSMutableArray it is going to be stored perfectly. but when i am going to show image in the below code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIImageView* imagePhoto;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableFriends dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    imagePhoto= [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(43.0,10.0,40, 40)] autorelease]; 

    if ([arrEmail count] != 0) 
    {
        imagePhoto.image = [arrImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imagePhoto];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrEmail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    }
    return cell;
}
```

it works perfecly when the image is called from here `img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];` but when the image is called from address book it gives me error of `EXCBAD Error` whats wrong in that code? how can i store image in NSMutabeArray and show the image?

hey help me any body can help me or suggest me to implement like [Google Latitude](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/google-latitude/id306586497?mt=8)
in this you can see in add friends from iPhone address book i want to just implement some what like this application functionality my all code is working good only i can't get images from address book please help me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have stored the image in a object of NSMutableDictionary like this

personrecord is the instance of

```
ABRecordRef
```

Assuming you are building the project in ARC mode.

```
 NSData  *imgData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *) ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(personrecord, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

            if (imgData)
            {
                UIImage *personImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                imgData = nil;
                [dict setValue:personImage forKey:@"UserImage"];
            }
            else
            {
                UIImage *personImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defalt_contact_img.png"];
                [dict setValue:personImage forKey:@"UserImage"];
            }
```

You may manipulate the code to suit your requirement, i am using dictionary and you are using arrays so you may use the addObject method of the array to store the image,

i always prefer to get the records from the address book in an mutable array with multiple dictionaries in this way the manipulation of records becomes easy.

Answer (score 2):

try to check if image is available or not using

> ```
> if( ABPersonHasImageData( person ) ) {
>        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)]
>     }
> ```

Comment: have you seen my code i have already tried this but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to check condition that there is image available or not.

```
NSData *data = (NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

if(img != nil)
{
  // assign the image here
}
else
{
  img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
}
```

i have just clear out your code. i think this may help.

Comment: i have tried like this but it still gives me same error. does any one can help me.?

Comment: try this 
CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
if (imageData != nil)
{
UIImage* image = UIImage imageWithData:(NSData*)imageData;
}

Comment: i have already used like this but still it gives me error. i am another time trying this code by suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you can not add image object directly to and an array, you need to first convert the image in NSData and add in array, then while showing image convert the NSdata to image. Hope it helps.

Comment: i have tried a lot as you suggest but it gives me same.can you post me your running code for this problem?